# Capacitor/push-notifications - Android receives the notification but does not open the APP when tap at the notification

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

Considering as an initial situation that the application is closed, the device receives the notification normally, but does not open the application when tap at the notification.
That is, it does not execute what was defined in 'pushNotificationActionPerformed'.
When the APP is opened the notification working ok ( 'pushNotificationReceived' is listened).

**My code:**

capacitor.config.js:

```
    PushNotifications: {
      "presentationOptions": ["badge", "sound", "alert"]
    },
```

notification-app.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { ActionPerformed, PushNotifications, PushNotificationSchema, Token } from '@capacitor/push-notifications';

import { INotificacaoApp } from '../interfaces/INotificacaoApp';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationAppService {

  _dadosNotificacao: INotificacaoApp;

  constructor(
    private zone: NgZone,
  ) { }

  async setupFCM() {
    if (Capacitor.getPlatform() == 'web') {
      return;
    } else {
      try {
        let permStatus = await PushNotifications.checkPermissions();
        if (permStatus) {
          if (permStatus.receive === 'prompt') {
            let permStatus2 = await PushNotifications.requestPermissions();
            if (permStatus2) {
              if (permStatus2.receive !== 'granted') {
                console.log('Notification not granted')
                return;
              } else {
                await PushNotifications.register();
              }
            }
          } else {
            if (permStatus.receive !== 'granted') {
              console.log('Notification not granted')
              return;
            } else {
              await PushNotifications.register();
            }
          }
        }

        PushNotifications.addListener(
          'registration',
          async (token: Token) => {
            console.log('My token: ' + JSON.stringify(token));
          }
        );

        PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', async (error: any) => {
          console.log('Error no registro do token de notificacao: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });

        PushNotifications.addListener(
          'pushNotificationReceived',
          async (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
            this.zone.run(() => {
              if (notification.data
                && notification.data.dados) {
                this._dadosNotificacao = JSON.parse(notification.data.dados) as INotificacaoApp;
                console.log('recebeu notificacao')
                console.log(this._dadosNotificacao)
              }
            });
          }
        );

        PushNotifications.addListener(
          'pushNotificationActionPerformed',
          async (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
            console.log('Action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification.notification));
          }
        );

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`SetupFCM com erro`)
      }
    }
  }

  async RemoveListeners() {
    PushNotifications.removeAllListeners();
  }

}
```

**The above setupFCM routine is called in tabs.page.ts**

```
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private notificationAppService: NotificationAppService
  ) {
    this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
      this.notificationAppService.setupFCM();
    });
  }
```

**Versions:**

- npm: 9.1.1
- node: 18.12.1
- @capacitor/cli: 4.5.0
- @capacitor/core: 4.5.0
- @capacitor/android: 4.5.0
- @capacitor/ios: 4.5.0
- @capacitor/push-notifications: 4.1.2
- @angular/core: 14.2.10
- @ionic/angular: 6.3.7
- @ionic/cli: 6.20.4

**I tried several configuration adjustments, as shown in the files below:**

In **android/build.gradle:** - added classpath for google-services:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}
```

In **android/app/build.gradle:**
added google-services in plugins and added firebase-messaging dependency

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
...
dependencies {
     ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.5'
}
```

In **variable.gradle:** added firebaseMessagingVersion

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 22
    compileSdkVersion = 32
    targetSdkVersion = 32
    ...
    firebaseMessagingVersion = '23.0.5'
}
```

The file google-services.json is in **android/app** directory.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution. Please suggest if you found a solution for it.

Comment: Hello good day!
Unfortunately not… I still have the problem. The only suggestion I had was to switch from FCM to OneSignal, but I don’t have time at the moment for that task.